How do the PMC quests work under the PvE mode?
With the new Escape From Tarkov PvE mode, quests like Friend From the West - Part 1 are still in the mode but you cannot collect PMC tags in this mode.
How can you complete these quests that require other players or dogtags?

AI PMCs drop dog tags that you can use for quests and barters. They also count for any required PMC kill.
